# Casting UserControl ASP.control_name_ascx vs Control_Name - Advantages/Disadvantages?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, casting

Recently I dealt with a commercially available ASP.NET product that shall go unnamed. When poking around in the code, I noticed that there was usercontrol casting that looked like this:

```
Dim ctl As ASP.modules_controls_addressinput_ascx = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("AddressInput1"), ASP.modules_controls_addressinput_ascx)
```

More recently I needed to cast a usercontrol to its specific type in one of my own projects so I could access its public properties and naturally I copied the casting method from above, since I had not seen another way to do it.

However, when deploying the project with this type of casting it would "Build", but failed when I tried to "Publish" with the error "Unknown Type". After some tinkering, I realized that the type of the declared class would work as follows:

```
Dim ctl As Modules_Controls_AddressInput = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("AddressInput1"), Modules_Controls_AddressInput)
```

Where the usercontrol is declared like this in its ascx.vb file:

```
Partial Class Modules_Controls_AddressInput
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

And indeed, this also fixed the issue with publishing.

My question is what would compel someone to cast the first way vs the second way, especially when it means that publishing the project will fail?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but the first approach will cast your control to the compiled code in asp.net temp folder ***C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ProjectName*** but the second approach will cast it to a the class itself. In my work usually I use `LoadControl("UserControlPath")` to create an instance of any user control

```
Dim ctrl As MyControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx"), MyControl)
ctrl.Property1 = value1
ctrl.Property2 = value2
```

for more further information about user controls in `ASP.Net` you can refer to this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. +1 for explaining that this is referencing the ASP.NET temp folder, but you really didn't answer why someone would want to do so vs. casting to the class itself.